# Using iff expression in rdlc report with null check keeps giving errors

Tags: rdlc

In a rdlc report i'm using an expression to hide the row visibility.
If the expression is true the row is hidden.
The value of the field can be "Ja", "Nee" or Null. Only if it's "Ja" the row must be shown and the expression result should be false.
The expression

```
=Iif(Fields!Vleugel.Value Is Nothing,true,false)
```

is working but when I want to add the "Ja" condition like:

```
=Iif(Fields!Vleugel.Value Is Nothing,true,Iif(Fields!Vleugel.Value.Equals("Ja"),false,true))
```

it's causing an error like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when the field is null.

Can't figure out what's wrong since it's looks simular to examples I found.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the **Row Visilibily** property you don't have to write an iif statement, it is enough to give the expression that will hide the row, try this:

```
=Fields!Vleugel.Value Is Nothing
```